# $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is not a projective module

Tags: modules, projective-module

I want to show that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is not projective for $n\geq 2$. I choose the exact sequence $\mathbb Z\stackrel{\pi}\rightarrow\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\rightarrow 0,$ and from $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ choose the identity map, and let $\phi$ :$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$, if I can show there is no way the diagram is commuted, then it's done, namely $\text{id}=\phi\circ \pi$ can not be true for any $\phi$, but I am confused here, why it's not. Hope someone can help me with that, thanks in advance.

Comment: Projectives are direct summands of free. Is this (torsion)free?

Comment: Z is $\mathbb Z$, right? (Try to use the right mathematical symbols!)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is indecomposable, because any two nonzero subgroups have non trivial intersection. So the only projective quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $\phi:\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ is a homomorphism, then $\phi(i)$ must have finite order for all $i\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, since $i$ has finite order. But the only element of $\mathbb Z$ with finite order is $0$. So $\phi$ must be trivial, hence $\phi\circ \pi\ne \mathrm{id}$.

Answer (score 6):

More directly, an abelian group (i.e., a $\,\Bbb Z-$module) is projective iff it is a free abelian group, and clearly a torsion abelian group cannot be free.

Comment: You don't need projective <=> free (over PID) in order to see that projective => torsionfree.

Comment: Your answer has more meaning to me, for I don't know how to prove Z and the countable sum of Z is not free. Can you give me some help about this?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I don't understand your comment. Anyway, I think that's straighter.

Comment: @YACP Thanks a lot, I see that you have already give me a link there :)

Comment: @user53800, the result you're asking about is Baer's proof of the Baer-Specker group $\,\Bbb Z^{\Bbb N}\,$. The proof can be found in Kaplansky's book "Infinite Abelian Groups", but also in the following PDF: http://tinyurl.com/bkjfrxn . This group always intrigued me...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks very much, I have been confused of this for a long time. By the way, why the torsion abelian group can not be free, can you show me

Comment: @user53800, because it fulfills a non-trivial relation, which (abelian) free groups cannot.

Comment: @DonAntonio while can you show me by the definition, namely that we can not find a basis for the torsion group?

Comment: Of course: if for all $\,x\in A\,$ there exists $\,n\in\Bbb N\,\,\,s.t.\,\,\,nx=0\,$ ,then we can always find a non-trivial linear integral combination $\,a_1x_1+...+a_mx_m=0\,\,,\,x_i\in A\,\,,\,m_i\in \Bbb Z\,$...In fact, it is not hard to see the group isn't abelian free even if there is one single non-trivial torsion element in the group